# what in htaccess configuration, could cause redirects, and loading of the website time in range of minutes?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Why additional parameter in the url speeds website loading more than 100 times?

url:  somedomain.com/path, www.somedomain.com/path,
.htaccess which loading time is several minutes :

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.somedomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/somedomain\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^t/(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

url:  somedomain.com/t/path, www.somedomain.com/t/path,
.htaccess which using, pages loads in a second

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex /index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.somedomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/somedomain\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^t/(.+)$ public/index\.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: As I commented on other question that you can do this testing in Chrome dev tool and see which css/js/image loading is talking more time while loading the page.

Comment: Actually, now both files are slow. Yesterday one of them was fast. Do not know what could be the reason. The error is that there is too many redirects.

Comment: Your first redirect rule is wrong and may cause infinite redirects. Replace that with the rule I provided you in other post and completely clear cache. Then test in Chrome dev tool.